# How to use ApplicationUserManager when default constructor is being called?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to use the ApplicationUserManager instance in a different controller method but it's always null since only the default constructor is being called. Commenting out the default constructor prevents the controller from being created. Is there a way to force the parameterized constructor to be called or would it be better to pass the ApplicationUserManager to the service via the service method rather than the constructor?

```
public AccountController()
{
    var context = new MyContext();

    _userService = new UserService(context);
    _accountService = new AccountService(context, UserManager);

    _mailService = new MailService();
 }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
 {
     UserManager = userManager;
     SignInManager = signInManager;

     var context = new MyContext();
     _userService = new UserService(context);
     _accountService = new AccountService(context, UserManager);
     _mailService = new MailService();
  }
```

Comment: To call the other constructor, have you tried passing it parameters?

Comment: Perhaps consider using a dependency injection container. If you are using aspnet mvc, here are instruction for setting up asp.net identity with SimpleInjector. https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/597. This way, you don't have to worry about newing up these objects in code. The objects will automatically be created for you on the fly.

Comment: @arod Awesome thanks! Looks like the way to go so I'll give that a try.